# Scala json object as argument for case class

Tags: json, scala

I have a data source which is saved as json format string. what I want to do is to read every json record as a `case class` ,I am using `json4s` as the parser. and use the `extract` method to get the case class.

my class is like this:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

case class Order(
  order_id: String,
  buyer_id: String,
  seller_id: Long,
  price: Double
)
```

and the parsing code is:

```
file.map(parse(_).extract[Order])
```

but this is done out of the class, what I want is json string as a constructor function argument for `class Order`

but as far as I know, a case class constructor must use the default constructor.

so is there anyway to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use companion object for such purposes:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

case class Order(
  order_id: String,
  buyer_id: String,
  seller_id: Long,
  price: Double
)

object Order {
  def apply(file: File): Order = {
    file.map(parse(_).extract[Order])
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
val file = openFile(...)
val order = Order(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe also want `implicit`:

```
implicit def jsonStrToOrder(s: String): Order = parse(s).extract[Order]
val orders: List[Order] = file
```